# How to verify in jinja2 or python that a google app engine datastore query has no results?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

my question is related to Python with Google App Engine Datastore and Jinja2.

I've created a kind, called Channel, with two properties: content and userid.

```
class Channel(ndb.Model):
  content = ndb.StringProperty()
  userid = ndb.StringProperty()
```

The *userid* is the *userid* retrieved from the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) that can be obtained when the user is logged in.

When the user is logged in I run the following query against my Channel kind to retrieve the user's Channel:

```
channels = Channel.query(Channel.userid == user.user_id())
```

It works fine when the user has already created a channel and I can present the Channel results to the user with the following Jinja2 code:

```
{% for channel in channels %}
<p>userid: {{ channel.userid }} | content: {{ channel.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is when the user hasn't created the channel. The Jinja2 code show nothings, not even the "*userid:*" or "*| content:*" part and I'd like to display a message to the user when the query returns no results (each user can only create one channel), to guide him to create a new channel, but don't know for sure how to verify that in Python or Jinja2.

Answer (score 2):

Since `channels` is an iterator, you can't know what's there until you iterate over it.  However, you might as well just fetch the data like this:

```
channels = Channel.query(Channel.userid == user.user_id()).fetch()
```

Then you can just check to see if the list is empty or not like this:

```
{% if channels %}
{% for channel in channels %}
<p>userid: {{ channel.userid }} | content: {{ channel.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>No channels!</p>
{% endif %}
```